# Lifting an isogeny to a projective space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I am currently investigating secant varieties of elliptic curves and I was wondering if the following is true:
Let $\phi: E \rightarrow E'$ be an isogeny of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$ with kernel a cyclic group of order $p$, both embedded in $\mathbb{P}^n$ for some $n \geq 2$ with $n$ even.
Can this map then be extended to a map $\psi: \mathbb{P}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ ? If so, does it follow that $\psi$ sends the $k$th secant variety $Sec^k E$ to $Sec^k E'$ ? In addition, what is the degree of $\psi$ and what does the ramification looks like ?

Any answer or reference to a possible solution would be appreciated.

**Edit**: Both $E$ and $E'$ are embedded as degree $n+1$ curves.

Comment: No, typically it cannot be extended to projective space.  Every morphism $\psi$ pulls back $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$ to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d)$ for some $d\geq 0$.  Thus, if $\phi^*(\mathcal{O}(1)|_{E'})$ is not of the form $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d)|_E$ for any $d$, then $\phi$ does not extend.  For instance, if $E$ and $E'$ are elliptic curves embedded in $\mathbb{P}^4$ as curves of degree $5$, resp. degree $7$, then an isogeny $\phi:E\to E'$ of degree $p\neq 5$ does not extend.

Comment: Ok, I should have said, both are embedded in $\mathbb{P}^n$ as degree $n+1$ curves.

Comment: The answer is still no.  Even if the degree of $\phi^*\mathcal{O}(1)|_{E'}$ equals the degree of $\mathcal{O}(d)|_E$, these invertible sheaves need not be isomorphic.

Comment: Agreed, but still there is associated to $\phi$ a degree $p^n$-morphism $f$ going from $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1))$ to $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1))$ by associating to each hyperplane the points of intersection on $E$ and taking as image the hyperplane through the images under $\phi$ of these points. Can't $E$ and $E'$ be naturally embedded in these 2 spaces such that.$f$ is an extension of $\phi$ ?

Comment: "... associating to each hyperplane the points of intersection on $E$ and taking as image the hyperplane through the images under $\phi$ of these points."  For a general hyperplane $H$, $H\cap E$ consists of $n+1$ distinct points.  The images under $\phi$ of these $n+1$ points will typically span $\mathbb{P}^n$.  Thus, they are not contained in any single hyperplane.

Comment: And if both line bundles are $(n+1)O $ with $O$ the neutral element ?

Comment: "And if both line bundles ...?"  Now we are getting somewhere.  Up to choosing the origin in $E$ and $E'$, this is equivalent to assuming that $\phi^*\mathcal{O}(1)|_{E'}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}(d)|_E$.  In this case, the pullback map $\phi^*:H^0(E',\mathcal{O}(1)|_{E'})\to H^0(E,\mathcal{O}(d)|_E)$ is injective.  Assuming that $E$ and $E'$ are elliptic normal curves (i.e., they are linearly nondegenerate), then the restriction maps $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}(1))\to H^0(E',\mathcal{O}(1)|_{E'})$ and $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}(d))\to H^0(E,\mathcal{O}(d)|_E)$ are both surjective...

Comment: ... Thus, there exist linear maps (typically many of them), $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}(1))\to H^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}(d))$ compatible with $\phi^*$.  This defines a linear subsystem of the complete linear system of $\mathcal{O}(d)$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$.  Using Bertini's theorem, for a typical choice of linear map as above, the linear system is basepoint free.  Thus, there exists a morphism $\psi:\mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{P}^n$ such that $\psi^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ equals $\mathcal{O}(d)$ and such that $\psi$ extends $\phi$.

Comment: Right, but can I now make an extension $\psi$ such that the $\frac{n}{2}$-secant variety of $E$ is mapped to the $\frac{n}{2}$-secant variety of $E'$ ? And in addition, that this secant variety is the ramification locus of $\psi$ ?

Comment: The morphism $\psi$ maps lines in projective space to curves of degree $d$.